# How Can i get Charge and how to pass token id to charge in swift (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, stripe-payments

How to generate stripe token id, charge id in swift. Please, could anyone help on the generation of stripe payment in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do stripe payment configuration

```
        let configuration = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
    configuration.additionalPaymentMethods = .all
    configuration.appleMerchantIdentifier = "Your stripe identifier"
    configuration.canDeletePaymentMethods = true
    configuration.createCardSources = false

    let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient.sharedClient)
    paymentMethodViewController = STPPaymentMethodsViewController(configuration: configuration,
                                                                  theme: STPTheme.init(),
                                                                  customerContext: customerContext,
                                                                  delegate: self)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Code For ApiClient to generate ephermal key

```
 class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPEphemeralKeyProvider {

static let sharedClient = MyAPIClient()

func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
    let url = AppConstant.Server.EPHERMAL_KEY

    let user = UserDefaultManager.shared.readUser()
    let header: HTTPHeaders = ["api_token":  user.apiToken ?? "",
                               "Content-Type": "application/json"]

    Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .get,
                      parameters: [
        "api_version": apiVersion,
        "id": user.id ?? -1
        ],
        headers: header)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { responseJSON in
            switch responseJSON.result {
            case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String: AnyObject], nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            }
    }
}
```

}

Then in delegate method

```
   func paymentMethodsViewController(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController, didSelect paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod) {

    var paymentStripeId: String?
    if let source = paymentMethod as? STPSource {
        paymentStripeId = source.stripeID
    } else if let card = paymentMethod as? STPCard {
        self.stpCard = card
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not getting AppConstant.Server.EPHERMAL_KEY

Comment: EPHERMAL_KEY is the url which your backend developer gives you.

Comment: without url can i do the stripe payment?

Comment: can i do this below https://stripe.com/docs/charges/android as in ios ?

Answer (score -1):

Try out this method. From stripe document.

```
let cardParams = STPCardParams()
cardParams.number = "4242424242424242"
cardParams.expMonth = 10
cardParams.expYear = 2021
cardParams.cvc = "123"

STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams) { (token: STPToken?, error: Error?) in
    guard let token = token, error == nil else {
        // Present error to user...
        return
    }

    submitTokenToBackend(token, completion: { (error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            // Present error to user...
        }
        else {
            // Continue with payment...
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: getting this error stripCard.validateCardReturningError(&underlyingError)

Comment: could u please provide me a sample project